# Select "year" in string from Beautiful Soup output

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, filter

I am building a web scraper for car data. Using Beautiful Soup I gathered data from carsdirect.com. I want to filter only the cars with year model "2011 Highlander" This is my first project please be gentle and ELI5.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.carsdirect.com/used_cars/listings/toyota"
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

results = soup.find(id="mainWrapper")
job_elements = results.find_all("div", class_="infoCell")
for job_element in job_elements:
    print(job_element, end="\n"*2)
for job_element in job_elements:
    model_element = job_element.find("p", class_="ymmListRowTitle")
    ymm_element = job_element.find("p", class_="ymmListRowTrim")
    miles_element = job_element.find("div", class_="mileLine")
    price_element = job_element.find("div", class_="priceLine")
    contact_element = job_element.find("div", class_="contactBlock")
    print(model_element.text.strip(),ymm_element.text.strip())
    print(miles_element.text.strip())
    print(contact_element.text.strip())
    print()
    #scraped_cars = results.find_all("div", string=lambda text: "highlander" in text.lower())
```

Output:

2022 Toyota Corolla LE
47,087 mi
Cal Auto Net (3mi)

2018 Toyota Prius c Two
73,386 mi
Cal Auto Net (3mi)

2018 Toyota Camry SE
79,547 mi
Cal Auto Net (3mi)

Answer (score 1):

use regex `r"\d{4}"`

```
string = '2022 Toyota Corolla'
result = re.findall(r"\d{4}", string)
print(result[0])
```

`print 2022`

Comment: Or without a regular expression: `string.split()[0]`.